# iOS getcwd alternative

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, getcwd

I am porting my C++ OpenGL application to iOS, it uses getcwd function to load shaders. In iOS 'getcwd' returns just a slash and I can't do something. Or is there any good method to load files on iOS?

Edit: found a solution! POSIX-based code.

```
static char homePath[256];
char *DocumentsFolder(void)
{

char *p;

if (*homePath)
    return homePath;

if ((p = getenv("HOME")) != NULL) {
    strncpy(homePath, p, sizeof(homePath));

    strcat(homePath, "/Documents" );
    if (mkdir(homePath, 0777)) {
        if (errno != EEXIST)
            printf( "CAN NOT CREATE DIRECTORY\n" );
    }
    return homePath;
}
return ""; 
}
```

Comment: If you can use Objective-C, see `NSFileManager`. It has a method to get the current working directory.

Comment: where are the shader files?

Comment: I've placed them in xcode project/Data/shaders/shaderfile.

Comment: @MarcB You are kidding? Honestly, you need to understand sandboxing, bundles and "well known" folders. Actually, there are files and there's a filesystem, too of course.

Comment: Well, I managed this out by dropping files to /Documents/ and using code at top.